# Retrieve Alerts using the legacy REST API

Tags: api, rest, alerts, deepsecurity

Using the legacy REST API I was able to retrieve alerts following the documentation using Postman. (https://automation.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/legacy-rest/20_0/index.html?env=onprem#list_alert_types)

But since 1 week I can't retrieve those informations anymore by using the same parameters used before.

Here is what I do :

1. [Authenticating using valid user (https://SERVER_IP:PORT/rest/authentication/login)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOFys.png)
2. [Trying to retrieve alerts using the sID given after authenticating (https://SERVER_IP:PORT/rest/alerts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRLsT.png)

I don't understand why I can't retrieve those informations anymore since before I was able to do it.

Here is the [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf3kb.png) and the [version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLHID.png)

Any idea on what I'm missing ?

Comment: The alerts API is giving you an error response, so probably *something* has changed since when you were able to retrieve data. Can you share a screenshot of the complete postman screen with your error, so we can see what type of error it is, and the exact call being made? The error text seems to indicate a problem with a host/computer ID, which is odd, so the extra context would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've rebooted the server where deep is installed and now it's working back.